# Access Variables in Other Scenes

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to do an overlay scene with the player's score on it, but I have the variable inside an object in another scene.  How can I access that variable?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just broadcasting a message to the other scene instead.

Comment: Please expand your answer with details on how to do what you propose, so that other who find it can make use of it.

Comment: This is a "copy property" example, is it not?

Comment: hmmm. wait, that doesn't work